# In EA, why do UML Profiles included in a custom MDG Technology not appear in my Resources

Tags: customization, enterprise-architect

I am using Enterprise Architect 11.1 from Sparx and have defined a few customisations. In all I have:

- custom reports for document generation
- UML profiles for our specific modelling guidelines
- tagged values on our specific elements
- custom search queries
- special toolbars for using the profile elements
- a specific desktop-layout to help our users

Most of these customisations work when I package them in an MDG technology, but the UML Profiles do not appear in my "Resources". I can access them through tools in the Toolbox, but that is not sufficiant because:

1. the toolbox always switches my tools away when I navigate throught my project (I know this can be partially fixed by associating diagram-types, but that is not a solution for me)
2. some elements out of my profile do not work when I use them out of the toolbox (don't ask me why: that looks like a bug?)

So how can I get the custom UML Profiles to appear in the resource window when I package them in an MDG Technology? I would like that to work just like when I do an "Import Profile" by right-clicking on the UML Profiles.

Comment: Your question appears to be to broad and thus off-topic. To use a MDG you should not import it in the resources but use the Extensions/MDG/Advanced settings. See my write-up here: http://community.sparxsystems.com/tutorials/552-24intro-to-creating-a-mdg-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import an MDG Technology by right-clicking the MDG Technologies folder in the "Resources" window and selecting Import Technology. However, this is not the best way to work with MDG Technologies.

You should instead place the technology XML file in some specific directory (on a shared file server if you're in a networked environment), and then add that directory to EA's set of MDG Technology locations, which you do as follows.

1. Select Settings - MDG Technologies to open the "MDG Technologies" window.
2. Click the Advanced button to open the "MDG Technologies - Advanced" dialog.
3. Click the Add button, and select Add Path in the pop-up menu.
4. Browse to the directory where you've put the MDG Technology file and click OK.
5. Back in the "MDG Technologies" window, make sure your MDG Technology is selected, and click OK.

Your MDG Technology will then be fully integrated into EA just like the ones supplied by Sparx Systems (eg BPMN), so you will not need to use the "Resources" window at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I see this goes in the same direction as the first comment to my question and I have tried these things out. Unfortunately what I WANT is to be able to access the profiles in the resource window. So I have to conclude that this is not possible, I guess I need to find another question and formulate my requirement in another way. Maybe I need to go for toolbox customisations, I'research thatfurther before posting